# upgrade RHEL version 7.6 to RHEL 8.4 ( offline )

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, kernel

we are trying to upgrade our RHEL server 7.6 to RHEL 8.4

as

```
 leapp preupgrade --no-rhsm --enablerepo BaseOS --enablerepo AppStream
```

but finally we get the following errors

```
============================================================
                     UPGRADE INHIBITED
============================================================

Upgrade has been inhibited due to the following problems:
    1. Inhibitor: The installed OS version is not supported for the in-place upgrade to RHEL 8
    2. Inhibitor: Detected loaded kernel drivers which have been removed in RHEL 8. Upgrade cannot proceed.
    3. Inhibitor: Missing required answers in the answer file
Consult the pre-upgrade report for details and possible remediation.

============================================================
                     UPGRADE INHIBITED
============================================================
```

any idea how to continue from above stage?

note:

under  `/etc/leapp/files` , we set the following files

```
ls -ltr /etc/leapp/files
total 3100
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   47708 Aug 15 12:55 unsupported_pci_ids.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   20711 Aug 15 12:55 unsupported_driver_names.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3057300 Aug 15 12:55 pes-events.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   39703 Aug 15 12:55 repomap.csv


 more  /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.txt
Risk Factor: high (inhibitor)
Title: The installed OS version is not supported for the in-place upgrade to RHEL 8
Summary: The supported OS releases for the upgrade process:
 RHEL-ALT 7.6
RHEL-SAPHANA 7.7
RHEL 7.9
```

Comment: The inhibitors are explained in the upgrade documentation, starting with [the requirements](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/upgrading_from_rhel_7_to_rhel_8/planning-an-upgrade_upgrading-from-rhel-7-to-rhel-8) which address the first inhibitor. Have you read it?

Comment: yes but , I not see resolution regarding to the problems that are show from "UPGRADE INHIBITED"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Inhibitor: The installed OS version is not supported for the in-place upgrade to RHEL 8

You need to upgrade to the latest RHEL 7 minor version first (7.9), see [Supported in-place upgrade paths for Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/articles/4263361) (there are some exceptions for different architectures, but I assume these do not apply to you because you got this error).

> Inhibitor: Missing required answers in the answer file

Check the pre-upgrade report in `leapp-report.txt` and answer the questions. See the upgrade documentation [Chapter 3. Reviewing the pre-upgrade report](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/upgrading_from_rhel_7_to_rhel_8/reviewing-the-pre-upgrade-report_upgrading-from-rhel-7-to-rhel-8) for more details.

> Inhibitor: Detected loaded kernel drivers which have been removed in RHEL 8. Upgrade cannot proceed.

Removed drivers are also in the pre-upgrade report. Check which drivers were removed (full list is available [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/index#removed-device-drivers_hardware-enablement)) and unload the modules using `rmmod` before the upgrade.

Comment: It’s also important to understand what the removed drivers do — the upgrade to RHEL 8 might result in hardware no longer being usable.

Comment: see my update - from leapp-report.txt , you can see that  RHEL-ALT 7.6
 is supported , so why we need to upgrade the OS to 7.9 before upgrade to 8.4

Comment: You’re not running RHEL-ALT.